# Loading into columns with "DEFAULT" set from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table that has a column set with "DEFAULT" from its definition. After loading from a SSIS package (this "DEFAULT" column is ignored when mapping), the column does not have the default value, which is differently from what I manually insert a row.

Is there any way to enforce the default value at the table level instead of adding derived column or hard code in the script? Just curious.

Thank you

Comment: What is the difference between this and the question you asked here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511202/keep-default-value-in-the-destination-table-when-do-fast-load-in-ssis

Comment: also looks like a duplicate of this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616115/ssis-fill-unmapped-columns-in-table-in-ole-db-destination

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot keep the default value using SSIS as you want. You should modify the package to produce the default value